# How to capture an image save it in gallery convert to threshold and greyscale and store those images in a local server(XAMPP)

Tags: java, android, sql, json

I need to use the camera capture to click the image > save the image in the phone gallery> convert that image to greyscale and threshold and finally send the two converted images onto the server using php, JSON and Xampp(sql). Heres the code below. I know the greyscale & threshold function works properly.Please correct me where I went wrong.

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;  
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.ColorMatrix;
import android.graphics.ColorMatrixColorFilter;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ImageView.ScaleType;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class CamActivity extends Activity 
{      
    private ImageView img;
    int boundBoxInDp;
    private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888; 
    Button bt1,bt2,btn;
    ContentValues values;
    int serverResponseCode = 0;
    ProgressDialog dialog = null;           

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cam);

        img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);// Assign imageview
        BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) img.getDrawable();//get image drawable and assign to bitmap drawable
        final Bitmap bmap = drawable.getBitmap();//assign bitmap drawable to bmap which is a bitmap image variable

        ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();//
        bmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);// this and the line above can be ignored


        //START CAMERA ON LAUNCH OF PAGE
        Intent camera_intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        // Save code here
        File f = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "temp.png");
        camera_intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
        //Save code ends    

        startActivityForResult(camera_intent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
        //START CAMERA ON LAUNCH OF PAGE ENDS

        bt1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);//button to go to next page
        bt1.setOnClickListener (new OnClickListener()//click button to travel to the next page
        {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                img.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
                BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) img.getDrawable();
                drawable.setFilterBitmap(true);
                final Bitmap bmap = drawable.getBitmap();

                //convert starts WORKS 

                //convert Bitmap to grayscale 
                Bitmap imgToGreyScale;
                imgToGreyScale = toGrayscale(bmap);  

                //convert to threshold
                Bitmap imgToBlackWhite;
                imgToBlackWhite = ConvertToThreshold(imgToGreyScale); 

                //set Bitmap to imageView
                ImageView imgbit;
                imgbit = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                imgbit.getImageMatrix();
                imgbit.setImageBitmap(imgToBlackWhite);
                //              //conversion ends WORKS

                Intent intent2 = new Intent(CamActivity.this,QrCodeActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent2);


            }
        });
    }


    // FUNCTION STARTS--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    //Threshold Function -WORKS-
    public Bitmap ConvertToThreshold(Bitmap anythingBmap)
    {
        int width = anythingBmap.getWidth();
        int height = anythingBmap.getHeight();
        int threshold = 120;
        for(int x=0;x<width;x++){
            for(int y=0;y<height;y++){

                int pixel = anythingBmap.getPixel(x, y);
                int gray = Color.red(pixel);
                if(gray < threshold){
                    anythingBmap.setPixel(x, y, 0xFF000000);
                } else{
                    anythingBmap.setPixel(x, y, 0xFFFFFFFF);
                }
            }
        }
        return anythingBmap;
    }
    //Threshold function ends

    // Grayscale Function -WORKS-
    public Bitmap toGrayscale(Bitmap bmpOriginal){        
        int width, height;
        height = bmpOriginal.getHeight();
        width = bmpOriginal.getWidth();    

        Bitmap bmpGrayscale = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
        Canvas c = new Canvas(bmpGrayscale);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix();
        cm.setSaturation(0);
        ColorMatrixColorFilter f = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm);
        paint.setColorFilter(f);
        c.drawBitmap(bmpOriginal, 0, 0, paint);
        return bmpGrayscale;
    }
    // Grayscale Function ends

    //FUNCTIONS ENDS----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    

    //ONResult activity to get image
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
    {                   
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) 
        { 
            // IMAGEVIEW QUALITY WORKS and only one time temp save.
            //      

            {

                File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString());
                for (File temp : f.listFiles()) {
                    if (temp.getName().equals("temp.png")) {
                        f = temp;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                try {
                    Bitmap bitmap;
                    BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath(),bitmapOptions); 
                    img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    String path = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ File.separator
                            + "sdcard" + File.separator + "sdcard";
                    //f.delete();
                    OutputStream outFile = null;

                    File file = new File(path, String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".png" +"");
                    try 
                    {
                        outFile = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outFile);// Can Change to JPEG also
                        // the above line of code doesnt matter as it doesnt change the quality.
                        outFile.flush();
                        outFile.close();
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        } 
    }

}
```

Comment: what is wrong? what is the error you are seeing? please describe the problem

Comment: @NirMH, What occurs is that it gets saved as a temp file in the gallery and gets overwritten every time I click, I also don't know how to save the image after it gets converted into threshold and greyscale into the server. I want to also save each photo in color before it gets converted into greyscale and threshold.I don't understand what kind of php code do i need to utilise. I'd be extremely thankful if you could help